# Most useful free jquery plugins for image manipulation

Tags: jquery, image, plugins

I have to make php project having features of image manipulation.
I have searched many plugins but no one was giving max 4 features.
Please suggest me full proof jquery plugin(or 2,3) which can fulfill my maximum of needs.

```
Image orientation
Cropping an image 
Noise reduction 
Zoom In and Zoom Out 
Resizing 
Selective color change 
Selecting and merging of images 
Sharpening and softening images 
Contrast change and brightening 
if possible, Special effects & animation
```

It would be very nice if plugin having all features.

Update:
Please give me plugins and features provided by that plugin out of above features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For animations you could use jquery UI. it provides lot of features like dropable, dragable and so on...

zooming:
jQZoom Evolution

rotating:
Wilq32.RotateImage

cropping:
Jcrop

color changes can be applied by css3

Answer (score 1):

It's not a jQuery plugin (just regular JS), but [Camjs](http://camanjs.com/) is pretty good, it's free and has good documentation.  Admittedly at the moment however it doesn't support all your needs but it also allows for plugins so it's possible to add any custom behavour you require.

Of your list, by default it supports for controlling: Contrast, Brightness, Clipping and has a couple of special effects (well you can make an image Sepia or Grey Scale at least!), as well as quite a few other standard features (see the [docs](http://camanjs.com/docs/)).

Note: this works using the `Canvas` element, this is because it allows you to render and image to it, then directly manipulate the pixel values rendered inside it.  This means that it doesn't work in older-browsers.  However, without the ability to alter individual pixel values, you may find that it's not possible to get all the effects you need (e.g. altering a specific colour in an image, image noise reductions, etc.).

Comment: It is not supported by most of the browsers. And I am interested in jquery plugin. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know that there is anyway to get the kind of advanced image manipulation techniques working on low-end browsers.  Many of the things you want rely on being able to manipulate the definition of the image itself, so without the canvas element it might not be possible/extremely hard.